# Check if the value is greater than or equal to the nearest lowest 0.05 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to check whether a decimal value is greater than or equal to the nearest low 0.05 value

**Example**

```
Value | Expected Nearest 0.05 value 
11.10 |    11.05           
11.11 |    11.10           
11.12 |    11.10           
11.13 |    11.10           
11.14 |    11.10           
11.15 |    11.10
```

I tried using the formula

```
parseFloat((Math.floor(value * 20) / 20).toFixed(2))
```

But it fails for 11.10 and 11.15. Using the above formula I get the output same as the value but the expected values are different. Which formula should I use to fix the above test cases.

Comment: The nearest 0.05 to 11.10 being 11.05 seems misleading to me, is that intentional? Surely 11.10 is closer to... 11.10

Comment: Yes it is intentional

Comment: Shouldn't nearest to 11.13 be 11.15 instead of 11.10?

Comment: It should be the near to the lower 0.05 value

Comment: what abput the other five values (x.x6 ....x.x9)?

Comment: So you don't actually want the nearest 0.05 multiple - you want the closest below?

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan yes

Comment: @NinaScholz for values (x.x6 ....x.x9) it will x.x5

Comment: But, if you want the closest below, then "I want to check whether a decimal value is greater than or equal to the nearest low 0.05 value", will always be false, surely?

Comment: Suppose the value is 11.14 and the closest below 0.05 value is 11.10, then 
11.14 >= 11.10 is true

Comment: Right, I read that the wrong way around. But then won't it always be true?

Comment: Yes it should be true

Comment: What about 11.101? Would that be 11.10 (seems logical), or 11.05?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could take an offset and take a multiple floored value.

```js
const format = f => Math.floor((f - 0.01) * 20) / 20;

console.log([11.10, 11.11, 11.12, 11.13, 11.14, 11.15, 11.16, 11.17, 11.18, 11.19].map(format));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It seems worth mentioning that this specifically works for input values with a maximum of 2 decimal places. To get this to work with any amount of decimal places you could subtract `Number.MIN_VALUE` instead of `0.01`

Answer (score 5):

You can multiply the values by 100 to temporarily remove the needed two decimal points, the nearest number now becomes a multiple of 5, you can then remove the rest of the Euclidean division by 5 and get what you want.

And since an exact multiple of 5 needs to be brought to the nearest lower value, you can conditionally remove a 5 when the rest is equal to 0.

The formule function could be something like:

```js
const f = (v) => (((Math.floor(v*100) - (Math.floor(v*100) % 5 || 5)) / 100).toFixed(2));
console.log('11.10', f(11.10));
console.log('11.11', f(11.11));
console.log('11.12', f(11.12));
console.log('11.13', f(11.13));
console.log('11.14', f(11.14));
console.log('11.15', f(11.15));
```

Comment: For 11.10 and 11.15 the output is not as expected.

Comment: For 11.10 -> 11.05 and 11.15 -> 11.10

Comment: So the expected value should always be strictly lower than the the value itself?

Comment: Yes it should be strictly lower

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Can you please tell me what exactly this `.... (Math.floor(v*100) % 5 || 5) ...` does? And why you use it?

Comment: @MaikLowrey This answer is essentially a more concise version of [Andrew Corrigan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70591676/157957) - the `|| 5` is doing the same job as the `if (remainder == 0) { remainder = 5; }`

Comment: @IMSoP Thank you very much! Now it is clearer!

Answer (score 2):

Whether my way is the most efficient I'm not sure, but here's how I would do it:

```
var x = Math.floor(value * 100);

var remainder = x % 5;

if (remainder == 0) {
   // deal with dropping down the 11.10 to 11.05
   remainder = 5
}

var result = parseFloat((x - remainder) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

HOWEVER, this only works for values that are 2 decimal places - to account for the third decimal place, you'd need to tweak it to:

```
var x = value * 100;

var remainder = x % 5;

if (remainder == 0) {
   // deal with dropping down the 11.10 to 11.05
   remainder = 5
}

var result = parseFloat((x - remainder) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

What I understand from your question is that you want the nearest lowest of the value and the answer should be less than the value itself.
So n being the number you need the lowest multiple of and v being the value, maybe you can try something like:

```
const nearestMultiple = (v) => (Math.floor((v - 0.001) /n) * n).toFixed(2);
```

The basic formula for finding a multiple would be `Math.floor((v/n) * n)` but for your unique case, we don't want the function to return the given number thus the subtracted 0.001.